# Heroku - Page Doesn't Exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Getting an error that my page doesn't exist when trying to reach my application.  It works locally, but not on the system, i have run rake and routes and restart, with no resolve.  The "Page Doesn't" Exist does show my custom favicon though.  THIS IS A SIMPLE ONE PAGE APP FOR USE WITHIN MY PERSONAL COMPANY I OWN, VERY BASIC, nothing over the top, one set of scaffolds and thats it.... Was developed in RubyMine

Routes File:

```
BoothLeads::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :leads


  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
   #root :to => 'leads#index.html'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

Migrate

```
class CreateLeads < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :leads do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :address
      t.string :phone
      t.text :interest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

LEADS CONTROLLER

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /leads
  # GET /leads.json
  def index
    @leads = Lead.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @leads }
    end
  end

  # GET /leads/1
  # GET /leads/1.json
  def show
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @lead }
    end
  end

  # GET /leads/new
  # GET /leads/new.json
  def new
    @lead = Lead.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @lead }
    end
  end

  # GET /leads/1/edit
  def edit
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /leads
  # POST /leads.json
  def create
    @lead = Lead.new(params[:lead])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @lead.save
        format.html { redirect_to @lead, notice: 'Lead was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @lead, status: :created, location: @lead }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @lead.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /leads/1
  # PUT /leads/1.json
  def update
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @lead.update_attributes(params[:lead])
        format.html { redirect_to @lead, notice: 'Lead was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @lead.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /leads/1
  # DELETE /leads/1.json
  def destroy
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
    @lead.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to leads_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Anything else needed let me know.

Thanks for the help.

CMD PROMPT: Heroku Logs

```
C:\Users\Jeff Gray\RubymineProjects\BoothLeads>heroku logs
2013-04-01T05:34:12+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 218ms (Views: 61.9ms |
 ActiveRecord: 63.6ms)
2013-04-01T05:34:13+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/applic
ation-01780e1cf08fc467414520399232647f.css host=peaceful-chamber-6371.herokuapp.
com fwd="110.32.193.201" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=32ms status=200 bytes=25
4629
2013-04-01T05:34:13+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/applic
ation-5909661ad10a83c2e0ae36fac77e7706.js host=peaceful-chamber-6371.herokuapp.c
om fwd="110.32.193.201" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=128
395
2013-04-01T05:34:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-04-01T05:34:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server
.rb:90:in `select'
2013-04-01T05:34:22+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-04-01 05:34:22] ERROR SignalExceptio
n: SIGTERM
2013-04-01T05:34:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKI
LL
2013-04-01T05:34:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least on
e process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-04-01T05:34:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-04-01T05:37:42+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exe
c rake db:migrate` by jeff.slim.gray@gmail.com
2013-04-01T05:37:45+00:00 heroku[run.2185]: Awaiting client
2013-04-01T05:37:45+00:00 heroku[run.2185]: Starting process with command `bundl
e exec rake db:migrate`
2013-04-01T05:37:46+00:00 heroku[run.2185]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-01T05:37:54+00:00 heroku[run.2185]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-01T05:37:54+00:00 heroku[run.2185]: State changed from up to complete
2013-04-01T05:38:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-04-01T05:38:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle e
xec rails server -p 47627`
2013-04-01T05:38:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-04-01T05:38:04+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-04-01 05:38:04] ERROR SignalExceptio
n: SIGTERM
2013-04-01T05:38:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server
.rb:90:in `select'
2013-04-01T05:38:06+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-st
yle plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rail
s 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your ap
p as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes f
or more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been
-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-04-01T05:38:06+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-st
yle plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rail
s 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your ap
p as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes f
or more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been
-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-04-01T05:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-04-01T05:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application starting in pr
oduction on http://0.0.0.0:47627
2013-04-01T05:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-04-01T05:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-04-01T05:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABA
SE_URL
2013-04-01T05:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-04-01 05:38:10] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (20
11-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-04-01T05:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-04-01 05:38:10] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-04-01T05:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-04-01 05:38:10] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPS
erver#start: pid=2 port=47627
2013-04-01T05:38:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-01T05:38:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least on
e process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-04-01T05:38:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKI
LL
2013-04-01T05:38:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=peacefu
l-chamber-6371.herokuapp.com fwd="75.170.18.86" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=1
94ms status=404 bytes=728
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 75.170.18.86 at 2013-0
4-01 05:38:35 +0000
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
ort-3.2.12/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route m
atches [GET] "/"):
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
ort-3.2.12/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5
/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5
/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:i
n `fetch'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5
/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5
/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.12/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5
/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpse
rver.rb:111:in `service'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpse
rver.rb:70:in `run'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server
.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2013-04-01T05:38:36+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 75.170.18.86 at 2013-0
4-01 05:39:44 +0000
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route m
atches [GET] "/"):
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
ort-3.2.12/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5
/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5
/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
ort-3.2.12/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5
/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5
/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=peacefu
l-chamber-6371.herokuapp.com fwd="75.170.18.86" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4
6ms status=404 bytes=728
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
.2.12/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpse
rver.rb:111:in `service'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server
.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpse
rver.rb:70:in `run'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5
/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-04-01T05:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-04-01T05:39:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/leads" for 110.32.193.201 at
 2013-04-01 05:39:54 +0000
2013-04-01T05:39:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LeadsController#index as HTM
L
2013-04-01T05:39:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered leads/index.html.erb within lay
outs/application (12.6ms)
2013-04-01T05:39:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 207ms (Views: 60.8ms |
 ActiveRecord: 60.4ms)
2013-04-01T05:39:54+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/leads host=pe
aceful-chamber-6371.herokuapp.com fwd="110.32.193.201" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms se
rvice=228ms status=304 bytes=0
```

Production.rb

```
    BoothLeads::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true


  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

Development.rb

```
BoothLeads::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

Cat/Config/Routes.rb

```
C:\Users\Jeff Gray\RubymineProjects\BoothLeads>heroku run cat config/routes.rb
Running `cat config/routes.rb` attached to terminal... up, run.2943
BoothLeads::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :solds


  resources :leads


  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):

  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'welcome#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful ap
plications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GE
T requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to access? Just the root? Or /leads?

Comment: the localurl is localhost:3000/leads

heroku site is: http://peaceful-chamber-6371.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Please run `heroku logs` and add it to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pages are actually coming up (try http://peaceful-chamber-6371.herokuapp.com/leads), it's just that there's no route defined for the root (http://peaceful-chamber-6371.herokuapp.com/).

Since you intend this to be a single-page site, I'd "move" leads up to the root:

```
BoothLeads::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :leads, path: ''
end
```

That will make your leads available at localhost:3000 locally, and at http://peaceful-chamber-6371.herokuapp.com/ on Heroku.

Comment: by one page i mean, its just the sub pages of leads... which is a scaffold, so add the information and it lists it, the navigation bar is just full of external links.

Comment: Ok. As long as LeadsController.index is a good place for people to land when they enter the URL, my answer is probably what you want.

Comment: tried that.... still errors out both with empty '' and the http:// link...


please forgive me as i am new to uploading to heroku

Comment: Ok, let me make sure there's nothing going wrong with any individual step. If you replace your routes.rb with the one in my answer, then restart your local server, does `http://localhost:3000/` (with no /leads) work?

Comment: Ok. If you then checkin routes.rb, then `git push heroku master`, and maybe `heroku restart` to be safe, does http://peaceful-chamber-6371.herokuapp.com/ then come up?

Comment: in production.rb  i did change this though

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

Comment: added my production.rb and development.rb code to up top..... if you look at "page source" its my 404 page that heroku is putting out... just fyi.

Comment: I think your environments are ok. I can't figure out why the routes are working for you locally (i.e. you don't have to add /leads after localhost:3000 any more) but it's still not working on Heroku. Can you post the results of `heroku run cat config/routes.rb `?

Comment: I will post them up right now(will post in original question to keep everything together)..... here is another weird thing....... IDK if heroku is taking my pushes!!!! my "activity" log shows nothing in the last two hours under "activity" in my heroku app account..... do we need to push to a new database and see if it takes the changes?????  SIDE NOTE SIDE NOTE SIDE NOTE:::: YOu can see from that cat config test that its not updating my routes.. that is probably the issue, its not taking the push? solution for that?

Comment: Haha, I never even noticed the Heroku activity log, that's useful. The lack of pushes is definitely your problem, you can see that your routes.rb file up on heroku doesn't have the `path: ''` part. So yes, I'd try pushing to a new Heroku app.

Comment: Also, you can check `git status` to make sure there's no "changes not staged for commit" or "changes to be committed".

Answer (score 1):

Did you migrate your database?

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Did you scale your app?

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Comment: just ran heroku ps:scale web=1 ... restarted and well, we still have nothing.

Comment: Oh man, thanks for the db:migrate... I actaully thought it was doing that automagically - didn't show up as a step in either of the guides I watched.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Rails 4.0?  If so, is your app in the early stages and still using the default Rails Application page as the home page / root?  If so, in Rails 4 this static page no longer exists, and will give a 404 error once migrated to Heroku.  To fix it, you need to define an actual homepage, and set the root in the routes file.