# heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

When I run the command "git push -f heroku", I get the following problem:

> Fetching repository, done.
>   Counting objects: 55, done.
>   Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (35/35), 9.26 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
>   Total 35 (delta 20), reused 14 (delta 2)
>
> -----> Removing .DS_Store files
>
> -----> Ruby app detected
>
> -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
>
> -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
>
> -----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
>
> ```
>    Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
>    Old: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
>    New: ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-linux]
>    Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
>    You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
>    your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
>    updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
>    You have deleted from the Gemfile:
>    * geocoder
>    Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
>    your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
>    updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
>
>    You have deleted from the Gemfile:
>    * geocoder
> ```
>
> !
>    !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
>    !
>
> !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
>
> To git@heroku.com:tummystuffer.git
>    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:tummystuffer.git'

So I added the gem 'geocoder' inside of my Gemfile, removed Gemfile.lock, ran "bundle install", "git add", "git commit", and pushed again, but got the same exact error.

I tried to solve the problem from this: [heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737296/heroku-push-rejected-failed-to-compile-ruby-rails-app), but still gave me the same error.

I've ran "gem cleanup" and ran "gem update" as well, but did not work.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Rails defaults
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

# rails-bootstrap
gem 'activerecord-tableless'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'simple_form', '>= 3.0.0.rc'
group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'better_errors'
gem 'quiet_assets'
end
group :production do
gem 'pg'
gem 'thin'
gem 'rails_on_heroku'
end
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'mail'
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'best_in_place'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'geocoder'
```

EDIT:

Here is my Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
remote: https://rubygems.org/
specs:
actionmailer (4.1.0)
actionpack (= 4.1.0)
actionview (= 4.1.0)
mail (~> 2.5.4)
actionpack (4.1.0)
actionview (= 4.1.0)
activesupport (= 4.1.0)
rack (~> 1.5.2)
rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
actionview (4.1.0)
activesupport (= 4.1.0)
builder (~> 3.1)
erubis (~> 2.7.0)
activemodel (4.1.0)
activesupport (= 4.1.0)
builder (~> 3.1)
activerecord (4.1.0)
activemodel (= 4.1.0)
activesupport (= 4.1.0)
arel (~> 5.0.0)
activerecord-tableless (1.3.3)
activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
activesupport (4.1.0)
i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
minitest (~> 5.1)
thread_safe (~> 0.1)
tzinfo (~> 1.1)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
best_in_place (0.2.3)
rails (>= 3.0.0)
better_errors (1.1.0)
coderay (>= 1.0.0)
erubis (>= 2.6.6)
bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)
sass (~> 3.2)
builder (3.2.2)
coderay (1.1.0)
coffee-rails (4.0.1)
coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source
execjs
coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
commonjs (0.2.7)
daemons (1.1.9)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
execjs (2.0.2)
faraday (0.9.0)
multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
figaro (0.7.0)
bundler (~> 1.0)
rails (>= 3, < 5)
font-awesome-rails (4.0.3.1)
railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
geocoder (1.2.0)
google_drive (0.3.9)
nokogiri (>= 1.4.4, != 1.5.2, != 1.5.1)
oauth (>= 0.3.6)
oauth2 (>= 0.5.0)
hashie (2.1.1)
high_voltage (2.1.0)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.9)
jbuilder (2.0.6)
activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
multi_json (~> 1.2)
jquery-rails (3.1.0)
railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
json (1.8.1)
jwt (0.1.11)
multi_json (>= 1.5)
less (2.5.0)
commonjs (~> 0.2.7)
less-rails (2.5.0)
actionpack (>= 3.1)
less (~> 2.5.0)
libv8 (3.16.14.3)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (~> 1.16)
treetop (~> 1.4.8)
mime-types (1.25.1)
mini_portile (0.5.3)
minitest (5.3.3)
multi_json (1.9.2)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
nokogiri (1.6.1)
mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (0.9.3)
faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
jwt (~> 0.1.8)
multi_json (~> 1.3)
multi_xml (~> 0.5)
rack (~> 1.2)
omniauth (1.2.1)
hashie (>= 1.2, < 3)
rack (~> 1.0)
omniauth-facebook (1.6.0)
omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.1)
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
oauth
omniauth (~> 1.0)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.2)
faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
multi_json (~> 1.3)
oauth2 (~> 0.9.3)
omniauth (~> 1.2)
omniauth-twitter (1.0.1)
multi_json (~> 1.3)
omniauth-oauth (~> 1.0)
pg (0.17.1)
polyglot (0.3.4)
quiet_assets (1.0.2)
railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rack (>= 1.0)
rails (4.1.0)
actionmailer (= 4.1.0)
actionpack (= 4.1.0)
actionview (= 4.1.0)
activemodel (= 4.1.0)
activerecord (= 4.1.0)
activesupport (= 4.1.0)
bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
railties (= 4.1.0)
sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
rails_on_heroku (0.0.2)
rails_serve_static_assets
rails_stdout_logging
rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
railties (4.1.0)
actionpack (= 4.1.0)
activesupport (= 4.1.0)
rake (>= 0.8.7)
thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
rake (10.3.1)
ref (1.0.5)
sass (3.2.19)
sass-rails (4.0.3)
railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
sass (~> 3.2.0)
sprockets (~> 2.8, <= 2.11.0)
sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
simple_form (3.1.0.rc1)
actionpack (~> 4.0)
activemodel (~> 4.0)
sprockets (2.11.0)
hike (~> 1.2)
multi_json (~> 1.0)
rack (~> 1.0)
tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
sprockets-rails (2.1.3)
actionpack (>= 3.0)
activesupport (>= 3.0)
sprockets (~> 2.8)
sqlite3 (1.3.9)
therubyracer (0.12.1)
libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
ref
thin (1.6.2)
daemons (>= 1.0.9)
eventmachine (>= 1.0.0)
rack (>= 1.0.0)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
polyglot
polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
turbolinks (2.2.2)
coffee-rails
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8)
actionpack (>= 3.1)
execjs
rails (>= 3.1)
railties (>= 3.1)
tzinfo (1.1.0)
thread_safe (~> 0.1)
uglifier (2.5.0)
execjs (>= 0.3.0)
json (>= 1.8.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
activerecord-tableless
best_in_place
better_errors
bootstrap-sass
coffee-rails (>= 4.0.0)
figaro
font-awesome-rails
geocoder
google_drive
high_voltage
jbuilder (>= 1.2)
jquery-rails
less-rails
mail
oauth2
omniauth-facebook
omniauth-twitter
pg
quiet_assets
rails (>= 4.0.0)
rails_on_heroku
sass-rails (>= 4.0.0)
simple_form (>= 3.0.0.rc)
sqlite3
therubyracer
thin
turbolinks
twitter-bootstrap-rails
uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: run `bundle install` before push to heroku.

Comment: Did you commit both Gemfile and Gemfile.lock ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But still gives me the same exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to solve the issue. I found out I was trying to push the project to another branch (not the master branch). I solved the issue by merging the branch with master branch and pushed it again.

Answer (score 5):

The error states:

> You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing your Gemfile. Run bundle install elsewhere and add the updated Gemfile.lock
>   to version control.

This basically means you've either not committed your `Gemfile.lock`, or have not run the `bundle install` command, which basically rebuilds `Gemfile.lock`. There's now a conflict which you'll have to resolve using `bundle install` on your development environment:

```
$ bundle install
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Geocoder"
$ git push -f heroku
```

Comment: I've done all of that, but still gives me the same exact error.

Comment: Can you look in your Gemfile.lock and let me know what's inside? Does it have geocoder mentioned anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I just edited my question and copied and pasted what's in Gemfile.lock into the question. It has geocoder mentioned in Gemfile.lock.

Comment: Can you remove `geocoder` from your `Gemfile.lock` and try again?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. A simple bundle install solved the problem for me. 
After `bundle install`, `git add .` and `git commit`, I pushed the code to heroku master and it worked! 
`$ git push -f heroku master`

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread but still relevant... I solved this by doing:
1) in the terminal create a new branch fixes

```
git checkout -b fixes
```

2) Delete gemfile.lock
3) In the gemfile replace gem 'squlite3' and gem 'pg' with this

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
end
```

4) run these commands in terminal

```
bundle update
bundle install --without production
git add .
git commit "Update files for heroku"
git checkout master
git merge fixes
git push -f heroku master
```