# "Deploy on Heroku" - Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Full context... I'm just trying to setup a fun ELO rating system for our office ping pong matches using https://github.com/elovation/elovation...

I was stoked to find it and thought it would be easy.

Buuuuut...

I'm running into issues.

I've been trying to Google and figure out solutions but every single answer is a bunch of command line-looking stuff and editing a Gemfile and using a `bundle install` command to fix it.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that through the process the README file tells me to do and I'm losing my mind.

There's a `RAILS_ENV` variable set to "production" in the setup form but I don't know if that is something I should change or what I'd even change it to.

Basically, I'm not a complete idiot when it comes to tech... But, also, I think I might just be dumb and missing something super simple.

Any help here would be the greatest. Thanks!
...

Here's the log:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 1.17.3
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
       Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-20/ruby-2.4.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
       Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-20/ruby-2.4.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
 !
 !     The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist on this stack.
 !     
 !     You are trying to install ruby-2.4.0 on heroku-20.
 !     
 !     Ruby ruby-2.4.0 is present on the following stacks:
 !     
 !     - heroku-18
 !     
 !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
 !     
 !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

edit: here's the form/page I'm looking at: [image]

edit2: Tried this from ***mu is too short*** after downloading the CLI:

*Like the error says, it is configured to use an old version of Ruby that is not supported on the current Heroku stack. Either you can downgrade your dyno to the old heroku-18 stack or try to upgrade the version of Ruby that elovation uses. Downgrading to heroku-18 is probably the easiest but beware that elovation is unmaintained and has several dependencies with security issues.*

Still gives me what looks like pretty much the same error?

```
Last login: Sat Nov 20 07:26:34 on ttys000
jakejohnson@Jakes-MacBook-Pro ~ % heroku login
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit: 
Opening browser to https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/cli/browser/ce7a8998-d5dd-4406-acd5-8f086d1f5e31?requestor=SFMyNTY.g2gDbQAAAA43My4xNjMuMTQ5LjIzN24GAGiTXD19AWIAAVGA.7u7MiKZ6EBv_y9C1X9aom-tXUK8itfOM-_EJEzD8moU
Logging in... done
Logged in as mynameisjacobj@gmail.com
jakejohnson@Jakes-MacBook-Pro ~ % heroku create --stack heroku-18
Creating app... done, ⬢ floating-reaches-04486, stack is heroku-18
https://floating-reaches-04486.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/floating-reaches-04486.git
jakejohnson@Jakes-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd ~/Desktop/nextphasepong
jakejohnson@Jakes-MacBook-Pro nextphasepong % git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/jakejohnson/Desktop/nextphasepong/.git/
jakejohnson@Jakes-MacBook-Pro nextphasepong % heroku git:remote -a nextphasepong
set git remote heroku to https://git.heroku.com/nextphasepong.git
jakejohnson@Jakes-MacBook-Pro nextphasepong % git add .          
jakejohnson@Jakes-MacBook-Pro nextphasepong % git commit -am "work dammit"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
jakejohnson@Jakes-MacBook-Pro nextphasepong % git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 180, done.
Counting objects: 100% (180/180), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (164/164), done.
Writing objects: 100% (180/180), 68.05 KiB | 3.58 MiB/s, done.
Total 180 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 1.17.3
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-20/ruby-2.4.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-20/ruby-2.4.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist on this stack.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     You are trying to install ruby-2.4.0 on heroku-20.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Ruby ruby-2.4.0 is present on the following stacks:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     - heroku-18
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to nextphasepong.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/nextphasepong.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/nextphasepong.git'
jakejohnson@Jakes-MacBook-Pro nextphasepong %
```

edit3: Several hours in... I might be the dumbest person in the world. I will literally Venmo someone $20 if they can give me a step-by-step rundown of how to set this thing up.

Comment: Like the error says, it is configured to use an old version of Ruby that is not supported on the current Heroku stack. Either you can downgrade your dyno to the old heroku-18 stack or try to upgrade the version of Ruby that elovation uses. [Downgrading to heroku-18](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-18-stack#using-heroku-18) is probably the easiest but beware that elovation is unmaintained and has several dependencies with security issues.

Comment: How do I access the command line interface? I guess I understand the error... I just don't understand how to apply the solutions people are sharing. It seems like the solution is relatively simple assuming I know where to type those commands in. The log is very clear about what the problem is but I'm not a developer. I've updated my question with a screenshot of what I'm looking at...

Comment: I think this should cover downloading and installing the CLI interface: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Comment: Ok, I have it downloaded. But I'm still getting the same error. I've now tried the following solutions: your... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737296/heroku-push-rejected-failed-to-compile-ruby-rails-app... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236559/heroku-push-rejected-failed-to-compile-ruby-app...

But I still am getting error. One of them recommended deleting the Gemfile.lock and that just gave me an error saying I shouldn't have done that heh. Added the log for your solution.