# failed compile from git-deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

please help solve the problem. i made on localhost rails4-application and push him on github. after i create account on heroku and connected to my github-repository and starting manual deploy.

in result i get follow error messages:

```
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_fec37d1bef82a4e579ae08ae57b76a1b/zlodiak-skladik_kartinok-6533f10/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/debugger-1.6.8 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_fec37d1bef82a4e579ae08ae57b76a1b/zlodiak-skladik_kartinok-6533f10/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/debugger-1.6.8/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot
       continue.
       Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I tried all the solutions to this topic: [heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737296/heroku-push-rejected-failed-to-compile-ruby-rails-app) 
but they did not help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install the debugger gem on Heroku and you probably don't want it there. Put it into a `development` group in your gem file so that it is available in your local development environment but not deployed in production, e.g.

```
group :development do
  gem 'debugger'
end
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#debugger-gems-fail-to-install for further explanation.