# heroku push rejected to agile-savannah even when sqlite is removed from gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I'm using Cloud9 IDE, running `Ruby -v 2.3.4p301` , `Rails -v 4.2.5`, and `Heroku -v heroku/7.4.1 linux-x64 node-v10.4.1`

I remove `sqlite3` from my database designation and get the gemfile designated below:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg' #postgress
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

I run
`bundle install`
`git status`
`git add -A`
`git commit -m 'initial commit'`
`git push`
`git push heroku master`

And get the error here:

> remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed. remote:  ! remote:  !
>   Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app. remote:  remote:  !
>   Push failed remote: Verifying deploy... remote:  remote: !       Push
>   rejected to agile-savannah-14413. remote:  To
>   https://git.heroku.com/agile-savannah-14413.git  ! [remote rejected]
>   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push
>   some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/agile-savannah-14413.git'

I came across the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737296/heroku-push-rejected-failed-to-compile-ruby-rails-app/19294832) but his problem was that he was using `sqlite3` for his database, but I removed that to use `postgress` instead.

I still follow the guidelines there and delete my `Gemfile.lock` file, then rerun the commands above and come across the same issue.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried running **RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile** locally?  The issue may not necessarily be due to heroku attempting to connect to the database.

Comment: no, what does that do? I'm pretty much brand new to ruby on rails

Comment: It does exactly what heroku is doing when you deploy.  You should be sure it works locally first.

Comment: well I did that and it worked fine, then I reran the push to heroku so it looks like it worked! thanks. would you want to type that up as an answer? just in case people run into this in the future. if not then I can but you should get credit for it.

Comment: Did you commit any changes to git after running the precompile, before pushing to heroku?  Running that command locally shouldn't have magically fixed your deployment problem.

Comment: You should read [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline), if you haven't already.

Comment: Well it now committed it to heroku, I checked and everything was there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173511/discussion-between-bill-doughty-and-logos-164).