# Heroku does not precompile assets when deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

It very clearly says in its documentation that it would do this if I don't precompile them locally.

And truthfully, I have no interest in precompiling these locally.

What I've had in **production.rb**, I've duplicated in **application.rb**

In my **production.rb** :

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compile = false

config.assets.precompile << 'application.js'
config.assets.precompile << 'application.css'
config.assets.precompile << 'screen.css'
```

Then I deploy, and that returns :

```
-----> Compiled slug size: 52.4MB
-----> Launching... done, v28
       http://myapp.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

So it "compiled" something, right? Except no go, I go to the site and the .css and .js files are blank.

In order to precompile this locally, I am required to comment out in **bootstraps_and_overrides.css** the line :

```
@import "screen.css.scss";
```

Then it precompiles locally, and my local machine will not load the css correctly, but *remotely* it will actually work correctly.

So my method of deployment now is comment out that line of code,

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add .
git commit -m "Adding public/assets"
git push heroku development:master
```

Then ( **unfortunately!** ) :

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean
```

And then uncomment that line of code in my .css.

Comment: Do you get an error in Heroku?

Comment: do you have RAILS_ENV=production on heroku

Comment: No errors. VelLes, how would I check that? I'm pretty sure its production, yes.

Comment: Try `heroku run rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Hmm nope it didn't change the state of the site. Running the process didn't return any errors.

Comment: Why "config.assets.compile = false" ? Where did you get this? It's compiling your app on Heroku, but not compiling your assets. You're explicitly telling it not to

Comment: I was under the impression that was only for assets that were not in fact precompiled. Am I wrong? Would changing that fix this?

Comment: @Trip can you add whole log from `git push heroku`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it would not deploy was because of Google fonts. Moving the file to your application.css such as :

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */


@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite);
```

Will allow the app to deploy, and for the fonts to work.

Answer (score 17):

Some things to check

1. You're on Cedar, right? Heroku only supports this behavior on Cedar.
2. You're on Rails 3, right? [Heroku doesn't support precompiling assets on Rails 4.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354539/heroku-does-not-compile-files-under-assets-piplines-in-rails-4)
3. You have asset pipeline turned on, right? in `config/application.rb` you need the line `config.assets.enabled = true`
4. You have to not have a `public/assets` folder. [On deployment Heroku decides whether or not to precompile based on whether this folder is present (even if it's empty)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline).
5. If the pipeline is on and you don't have an assets folder, then pre-compilation must be failing.

Comment: me too, i deleted public/assets.

Comment: Same. crazy nuance

Answer (score 2):

Try changing to this. I hope this will help you.

In config/environments/production.rb

`config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true`

Answer (score 0):

You might be on the wrong Heroku stack. Make sure you specify stack Cedar when you create apps that use the asset pipeline.

`heroku create -stack cedar`

Comment: On heroku's website, is says very explicitly that my app is a Cedar app. Is it possible that they are not?

Comment: Oh. Then that isn't the issue. I got nothin'.