# How to include custom css file in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `custom.css.scss` file in my `assets/stylesheets` folder where I've added new css.

All stylesheets work in development but in production the `custom.css` file isn't included ie no customm.css style changes are implemented in production.

In application.rb I have:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
config.assets.enabled = true
```

In production.rb I have:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

In my application.html.erb I have:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

In application.css I have:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

My app is on Heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems you are described may be related to [Heroku does not precompile assets when deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664802/heroku-does-not-precompile-assets-when-deploying)

As assets are precompiled for production, you may add it to config.assets.precompile in your environment.rb as described there  http://jalada.co.uk/2012/01/23/adding-files-to-config-assets-precompile-in-rails-3-1.html

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(custom.css)
```

Comment: Wouldn't *= require_tree . be sufficient?

Comment: hm, yes, it seems it should. Have you checked following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664802/heroku-does-not-precompile-assets-when-deploying ? May your problem be related to one of the items listed there?

Comment: Thanks Mike. I had to delete my public/assets folder. I've never had to do it before. Weird.

Comment: you are welcome. Based on it I've updated the answer to make it helpful