# Rails 4 images not loading on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have spent the better part of the day trying to get images to load on my heroku app.  Everything I try works locally, but not after being deployed to heroku.

I have png files saved in the images folder under my assets.  I am referencing these images with syntax in my css such as;

```
#signin {
  background: url(<%= asset_path 'sf.png' %>);
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

In heroku when I inspect the background the assets/sf.png link is there but when you click it it shows a broken image, suggesting it did not load properly.

I've tried toggling `config.serve_static_assets = false` in the `production.rb` file between true and false and neither works.

I also have

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Precompile is always successful.

Rails 4.  Any ideas on what else to try?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Another issue, I was having with this was that I was precompiling my assets locally, prior to loading it to heroku.  This requires you to follow a different set of steps, which can be found below.  If you precompile your assets locally, you must follow these steps or any updates you made to your assets folder will not be reflected in prod.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

`commit` and `push` to server.

Answer (score 92):

I needed to combine several solutions to make this work, here is what I did:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

in my **Heroku console**

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a yourapp
```

**production.rb**

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
config.assets.compile = true
```

I didn't need to precompile the assets locally.

Comment: I already had the gem, but other than that, `config.assets.compile = true` sufficed for me. Running Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0, on EU Cedar stack.

Comment: This is dirty fix since you will have runtime compiling due to `config.assets.compile = true`. It will work but it is not proper production setup.

Comment: No such feature: user-env-compile

Comment: Don't compile assets true on production. that makes production slow. 
Instead create `config/initializers/assets.rb`, and add these to it, so that rails production recognizes vendor and lib precompiled assets.

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)\z/`

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/`

Comment: @gwho, this doesn't seem to work for me. putting `config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf .png .jpg .gif)` in '/config/application.rb' helped me. will this solution slow down the production?

Comment: @lakesare interesting. it shouldn't slow it down. My solution is roughly the same as yours, except the `Rails.application.` is already called in the application.rb I will have to look into it. But the answer to your question should be a "no", since the intent is the same, and they both avoid live compilation.

Comment: Depracation warning from rails: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly.

Comment: I attempted to implement the above answer on Rails 5.0.1 and it broke the application completely upon pushing to Heroku. Just a heads up.

Comment: I'm trying the solution from @ahnbizcad.  It doesn't seem to affect anything.  Setting assets.compile to true is working for me, but if that affects performance speed, I would really like to find a better solution.  Is there possibly something else I need to do?   He mentioned that Rails.application is already called in application.rb.  I'm not sure how to tell whether my app is already doing that.

Comment: I also tried the solution from @lakesare.  No luck.

Comment: i suspect version drift

Answer (score 57):

You need to do two things to resolve it.
First, change these two lines from false to true in `production.rb` file.

```
      config.assets.compile = true
      config.assets.digest = true
```

Second, if you've syntax like this for your images

```
    background: url("imgo.jpg")
```

Change it to

```
     background: image-url("image.jpg")
```

I hope it does your job.

Comment: Yes!!! Nothing else worked for me but this did (setting `config.assets.compile` to `true`).

Comment: Yes this worked for me too!  Thanks!  Configuring:  config.assets.compile = true

Comment: Not sure why this isn't top comment. None of the other answers worked for me. You just saved me from wasting hours on this. I didn't need to mess with anything else except assets.compile.

Comment: 40 posts later, you finally answered my question. Thank you!

Comment: When I set config.assets.compile = false, I can see my app without loading any of the css, image, and ... files (They're not accessible). When I change it to true, I cannot see my website, but all files are accessible via their own link!! Do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: Setting config.assets.compile = true   will tremendously slow your app down and consume much more memory.  If you notice your pages rendering much slower in production, this is why!

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue and I solved it with the following line in the custom.css.scss.. Tell me if this works for you.

```
background: image-url('sf.png')
```

Referencing the asset being done different ways depending if you are using ERB or Sass, [see in the Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets).

Comment: This worked for me as well. I originally had: `background:url(file.png)` Changing it to `background:image-url('file.png')` did the trick.

Comment: this is the real solution.

Comment: i originally had `background-image: image-url('file.jpg')` and it sometimes worked but this works all the time :D

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the reputation to comment (yet) but it's important to note that the Heroku labs feature has been removed, so now you'll get a "No such feature: user-env-compile" error

More: https://github.com/Crowdtilt/CrowdtiltOpen/issues/251

Answer (score 2):

Rails ('4.1.5') I had a similar issue of images not showing on Heroku but showing up locally. I am not using paperclip or carrierwave gems, I precompile *locally* and also using *RAILS_ENV=production* I push to github and it deploys fine to Heroku.

I solved the issue by having:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.digest = true

// delete precompiled assets
bundle exec rake assets:clobber --trace
RAIL_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:clobber --trace
```

copied images to public/assets from app/assets. then:

```
// tests should pass
bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace

git commit
git push
```

And it was running fine on Heroku.

Comment: As others have stated, `config.assets.compile = true` is not suitable for production.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with showing just images. Being new to rails I did not know I could use:

`<%= image_tag("fileName.png", alt: "File Name Fancy", size: "100x100")%>`

Instead of traditional html.

The image_tag is explained in the rails api but I find its use is better explained here: 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

All I added to my app was this gem:
`gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`

As described in the heroku asset-pipeline documentation. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

I tried many solutions too but i found an invaluable solution and explanation
1. Heroku looks for assets in the public folder and that means you have to pre-compile your assets but if you were like me someone looking for a way to precompile my assets when my development environment is set to gem sqlite and production set to pg then you would do this.

in your production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

if you do not have gem pg installed you need to comment it out and change your production environment to use gem sqlite and run this

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

when all assets have been precompiled, switch back to your default settings and git add .,commit, and push to heroku

Answer (score -1):

The images won't  be served as assets by default, only css and js. You should look into the answer of

Syed Ehtsham Abbas in this question
[Heroku does NOT compile files under assets pipelines in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354539/heroku-does-not-compile-files-under-assets-piplines-in-rails-4)

Comment: that worked initially but after another recompile and another reload it broke

Comment: @brad can you post your product configuration ?