# Heroku staging environment not deploying all images and CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been struggling to have my Heroku staging environment mirror my local development environment. The first thing I am struggling with is my index page's slider image. It's being called with ERB in my index.html.erb file, but when I run bash and go into my heroku environment, the image isn't even there? Every other image from my assets/image folder is there except that one. All of my images are in assets/images. 
There are other subtleties such as different fonts and colours of progress bars that aren't being deployed properly. All of my css files are in assets/stylesheets.

**gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'devise', '3.0'
gem 'google-analytics-rails'
gem 'meta-tags'
gem 'databasedotcom'
gem 'databasedotcom-rails'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'thin'

group :development do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end 

gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', "~> 2.3.0"
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
```

**application.rb**

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Custom error messages
config.exceptions_app = self.routes

# Static assets 
config.assets.precompile = true 
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

**production.rb**

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = true

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Precompilation**

> All of my images are in assets/images

You must remember that [Heroku relies on `precompiled` assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) - so it will look in the `public/assets/images`, or `public/images` folder

When you're using `bash` to see whether the files exist, it would be far more robust to look in the `/public/images` folder, as this is where the precompiled assets would normally sit anyway

---

**Fix**

> There are other subtleties such as different fonts and colours of
>   progress bars that aren't being deployed properly

This could be a number of issues which are causing this:

> 1. Your assets may not be present
> 2. Your references to the assets may be incorrect

What I would do (and have done before) is firstly to precompile your assets locally, as `david` recommended. You can do that relatively simply:

```
$ rake asssets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This will populate your app's `public` folder with the relevant assets, which will be referenced by your various path helpers

-

Secondly, I would make sure those assets are being referenced properly. The way to do this is to use the various [`path helpers`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) which are embedded inside Rails - a prime example being [`asset_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) / [`asset_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
.test {
   background: asset_url("test.png");
}
```

This references the files regardless of whether they are precompiled or not; meaning that it will give you the ability to reference them in production. I would make sure your asset files have all the correct references in order to get things working again

Comment: I removed everything from my public folder on my development machine. Now I'm trying to precompile all my assets from my app/assets into the public folder and nothing is precompiling now. I pushed this change to my staging env and now I have my images working but that must mean they're not being served from public/assets cause there are none in there.

Comment: Even running rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production locally doesn't precompile assets to the public folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with images and Heroku, and this worked for me:

> Another issue I was having with this was that I was precompiling my
>   assets locally, prior to loading it to heroku. This requires you to
>   follow a different set of steps, which can be found below. If you
>   precompile your assets locally, you must follow these steps or any
>   updates you made to your assets folder will not be reflected in prod.
>
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline
>
> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
>
> commit and push to server.

From here: [Rails 4 images not loading on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324063/rails-4-images-not-loading-on-heroku)
(See the second answer)