# Heroku not displaying images or fonts in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

I've tried [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324063/rails-4-images-not-loading-on-heroku) [guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324063/rails-4-images-not-loading-on-heroku) on making images and fonts appear on Heroku but none seem to be working. Precompiling then pushing to Heroku and [changing images are referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4) doesn't seem to work either. Any help would be much appreciated. [Full source code here](https://github.com/adriangrantdotorg/urbanbook).

For example stylesheets/themes/default/style.css

```
.iconset {
  background-image: image-url("icon/top-tray.png")  no-repeat;
  background-image: url(image-path('icon/top-tray.png')) no-repeat;
  background-image: asset_path('icon/top-tray.png') no-repeat;
  background: url(<%= asset_path 'icon/top-tray.png' %>) no-repeat;
}
```

Renders as

```
.iconset {
  background-image: image-url("icon/top-tray.png")  no-repeat;
  background-image: url(image-path('icon/top-tray.png')) no-repeat;
  background-image: asset_path('icon/top-tray.png') no-repeat;
  background: url(<%= asset_path 'icon/top-tray.png' %>) no-repeat;
}
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compile = false
```

config/application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts', 'plugins', 'scss')

config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf .png .jpg .gif)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change `config.assets.compile = false` to `config.assets.compile = true` in the `config/environments/production.rb file`.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work @cyzanfar. The page doesn't fully load and not even the stylesheets. I've edited my question with more details, thanks