# Heroku assets not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have added new image in assets but after pushing on Heroku they remain there for few hours and again old images start displaying and i have also compiled Heroku assets but still new images disappear after few hours 
`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Please refer to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324063/rails-4-images-not-loading-on-heroku .

Answer (score 1):

Edit these two lines from false to true in production.rb file.

```
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
```

Second, if you've syntax like this for your images

```
background: url("imgo.jpg")
```

Change it to

```
 background: image-url("image.jpg")
```

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324063/rails-4-images-not-loading-on-heroku)