# Rails 4 app on Heroku is serving CSS and JS but not image assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I've deployed a Rails 4 app to Heroku and it serves my CSS and JS assets just fine but cannot find the images (404).

I have added `gem 'rails_12factor'` and tried toggling the `config.serve_static_assets = true` but to no avail (doesn't `rails_12factor` do that for you anyway?).

The strangest part is that it is nearly identical to another Rails 4 app I very recently deployed which has no issues with the assets. There are only a few differences between the two apps (from a config standpoint):

1. The broken one is deployed to Heroku's "warm-chamber" and the one which does serve images is deployed to "serene-earth".
2. The one which isn't serving images also has some settings for Sendgrid in production.rb:

   ```
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
   :port           => '587',
   :authentication => :plain,
   :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
   :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
   :domain         => 'heroku.com'
   }
   config.action_mailer.delivery_method ||= :smtp
   ```

   I can't imagine how that would affect anything meaningful.
3. The broken one has newrelic's `newrelic_rpm` gem installed, the working one does not.  It also makes use of the ENV variable management gem `figaro` and MailChimp's `gibbon` gem, which the working app does not.  Not sure how this would affect things, but you know better than I.

**Final note**: My first deploy after I'd added custom CSS and image files to the repo, even though I did have `rails_12factor` installed, showed some of the same strange errors as detailed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354539/heroku-does-not-compile-files-under-assets-piplines-in-rails-4), though they went away on my next deploy despite no meaningful changes (which seemed pretty odd):

```
    Running: rake assets:precompile
    I, [2013-10-05T04:25:02.831526 #626]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0eea2e50-5876-4521-b7f6-7ca902cb129b/public/assets/bg-c63ed011f04c5167903c6d603521adfb.jpg
    I, [2013-10-05T04:25:02.836773 #626]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0eea2e50-5876-4521-b7f6-7ca902cb129b/public/assets/coding_school-3bcbdaea6f8c23b774d27df4b608647a.jpg
    I, [2013-10-05T04:25:02.840352 #626]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0eea2e50-5876-4521-b7f6-7ca902cb129b/public/assets/down_arrow_select-0b10b4ac52a74389bbc3abbb3a8cde7a.jpg
    I, [2013-10-05T04:25:03.013966 #626]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0eea2e50-5876-4521-b7f6-7ca902cb129b/public/assets/application-0c6f0f27ac77563741a04576653d7c0e.css
    Asset precompilation completed (3.22s)
```

What could cause the app to serve CSS and JS fine but not images?

Why would it be different between my two almost identical apps?

Answer (score 4):

Setting `config.assets.compile=true` in `config/environments/production.rb` solved the issue but I still don't quite understand why the issue occurred.

Comment: This solved my problem too.  But I, like @Erik Trautman, do not know what the original issue was.

Answer (score 0):

A way to debug this scenario:

Open the production app in the browser (e.g. Chrome), open the developer tools, reload the page, check the requests for the images:

- Is the requested URL the one you expect (that is, does it have the MD5 checksum appended)? If checksum is missing: You might have inserted the images in a `<img src='/images/image.png'></img>` style when you should use Rails `<%= image_tag('image.png')` instead. Google for that helper.
- If the URL is as expected: What is the status and response of the image request? If it's `404`, make sure you've specified the path in your `image_tag` helper correctly (you might not need to prepend something like `/images` if you have it. Experiment a little till you find the answer.