# Active Admin Layout Not Display Proper In Production Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

My Active Admin Layout Not Comes in Production Environment.

I added in Gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

See My Active Admin Page
[image]

Help me Please.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: is it working on development ..?

Comment: is your assets are coming properly ?? have you pre-compiled the assets in the production.

Comment: it's working on development.

Comment: I pre-compiled the assets in the production but it's not display

Answer (score 0):

Im using Rails 4 and after running the server in RAILS_ENV=production i would get the same layout as you did, although it works in the development environment. after searching in the web for different answers that one that work for me was the next. [Heroku does NOT compile files under assets pipelines in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354539/heroku-does-not-compile-files-under-assets-pipelines-in-rails-4?rq=1) i find the answer here.

add rails_12factor to your gemfile

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

then

```
bundle install
```

and then restart your server

i did some modifications to config/application.rb file but it never worked for me (somthing to do with precompile assets) therefor i dont think it's necessary.

hope it helps