# rails assets not being properly precompiled by heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4.1

My assets are not being properly precompiled to my staging heroku app. I usually use `rake assets:precompile` before pushing but my senior developer told me not to use that and put `/public/assets` into gitignore saying that heroku will automatically `precompile` the assets. When I push, heroku says that it runs `rake assets:precompile` but none of my assets show up. The page is just html.

possible causes: before my senior developer told me his way, I ran `rake assets:precompile` and removed `/public/assets` from gitignore as I though it wasn't suppose to be there. But after he told me, I put /public/assets back into `.gitignore` and deleted all the public assets and the assets still are not working on the heroku staging app. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571492/1890135

I didn't specify this in the question but I was making a 2nd staging app not called staging so I had to add the `rails_12factor gem` under this new staging name environment.

```
group :staging_new, :staging, :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor' # To enable features such as static asset serving and logging on Heroku
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why did you include `public/assets` in your `gitignore` file anyway? There's no need for it to be in there, unless you've precompiled your assets locally & don't want to use them in Heroku?

--

A good way to test whether your app will work in `staging` is to run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`. This will do as Heroku would -- compiling your assets

What I would do initially is:

> - Precompile your assets locally (using `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`)
> - Check in your `public/assets` folder for the precompiled files
> - If they're there, push to Heroku & do again
> - If not, there will be another problem to fix

Generally, though, Heroku's precompilation process is just the same as you would do locally. So maybe you could even try running your Rails server in production mode to see what the issue might be; it's probably more your app than Heroku