# CSS doesn't work when deploy to Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, precompile

CSS doesn't work when I deploy my rails application to Heroku.

My `application.css.scss` has:

```css
@import 'normalize';
@import 'skeleton';
@import 'animate.min';
@import 'froala_editor.min.css';
@import 'froala_style.min.css';
@import 'font-awesome';

@import 'plugins/char_counter.min.css';
@import 'plugins/code_view.min.css';
@import 'plugins/colors.min.css';
@import 'plugins/emoticons.min.css';
@import 'plugins/file.min.css';
@import 'plugins/fullscreen.min.css';
@import 'plugins/image_manager.min.css';
@import 'plugins/image.min.css';
@import 'plugins/line_breaker.min.css';
@import 'plugins/table.min.css';
@import 'plugins/video.min.css';
```

I tried using gems like `rails_12factor`, `rails_serve_static_assets` and :

```
 config.serve_static_files = true
```

Also:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

http://cl.ly/0c0z0M3H2v13
http://cl.ly/0G0z0S331c22

Comment: Are you sure all the CSS files are being deployed correctly?

Comment: I didn't know about `config.assets.compile` in `my production.rb` it was false. Now it works :)

Comment: This question and answer might have future value. Please add that as an answer (i.e. "Answer your question"), with a little more explanation of what the option means, then accept it after the required waiting period (I think it's still 2 days?).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354539/heroku-does-not-compile-files-under-assets-pipelines-in-rails-4

Only I changed:

```
 config.assets.compile = false
```

By:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```