# 404 image is not showing

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have an image: **app/assets/images/oops.jpg**

In **404.html** I have:

```
<html>

<head>

  <title>Oops! Where are we?</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <style>
  body {
  background: url('oops.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


</body>
</html>
```

I confirmed that the image is indeed in production on **Heroku**, but the browser can not find the image.

Here is an image of my files.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: place the image in the same folder as the html page

Comment: background: url('../images/oops.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;

Comment: As long as I know, I maybe be wrong, if you use 'cover' you should use background-image i.p.o. background

Comment: @Serlite the CSS is in the HTML file.

Comment: @Franco I have tried using background-image, but it is still not working. What is the suggestion for the full line and I can try

Comment: You need first to be sure that your image path is correct. Can you tell me where your image is?

Comment: @Franco  the image path, from the very highest level, is: app/assets/images/oops.jpg    its a rails app

Comment: If this code is in the app directory you would try 'assets/images/oops.jpg'.

Answer (score 1):

Try image path as **"/assets/oops.jpg"** or **"../images/oops.jpg"** this one too in another case .
Assuming that you are using  ruby on rails app from your path that you have mentioned.
hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If your image is `app/assets/images/oops.jpg`

then your path to the image needs to be:

```
body {
  background: url('/app/assets/images/oops.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
  }
```

Comment: This returns a 440 not found

Comment: can you test in the browser with the full url to see if the image is loading: http://www.example.com/app/assets/images/oops.jpg

Comment: Or place the image in the root, and change the path to the image to url(/oops.jpg)

Comment: Interesting, it does not appear when I go to the equivalent of example.com/app/assets/images/oops.jpg. But I clearly see it in my repo. Thoughts on why this is?

Comment: did you upload your image to the server? Also, you might want to give the body a width and a height of 100% as well because it doesn't have any content

Comment: Yes, rails automatically complies assets, and I see it compiling the image when I push. I will try adding a width and height and see if it helps, but there is an error in my browser's console saying 404 not found for the image

Comment: If the image returns a 404 when you check in the browser, then there might be an issue with the compiling rather than the css path. Try uploading the image manually to the server.

Comment: And you're sure the name of the image (and extension) is correct?

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: Is app a folder on the server as well, or is assets in the root? If so then try this path: /assets/images/oops.jpg Make sure to test in the browser first to see if the image shows up

Comment: Here's a post that's related, maybe this is the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354539/heroku-does-not-compile-files-under-assets-pipelines-in-rails-4

Comment: Thanks! I saw that post previous to posting this. I have those gems set up. Also, I have several other images throughout the app, which work fine. I'm wondering if this is different since the rails 404.html page is in /public, instead of in views?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Ruby, maybe best to add Ruby tags to your question rather than css. My best bet however would be to place the image in the root and change the css path to the image to url(/oops.jpg)

Comment: okay, I'll keep working on that, and add ruby to the question. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
background: url('../images/oops.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Comment: I tried this and still got a 404 not found in browser console

Comment: background: url('/app/assets/images/oops.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
Try this

Comment: When answering you should explain why your solution is useful and how it works. Tossing out code doesn't educate, which is the goal. It's akin to handing someone a fish or teaching them to fish.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue while deploying a rails app on heroku in my case a little css change solved the problem

```
  body {
  background: asset-url('oops.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

use this asset-url instead of url property. hopefully it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

**instead ... 
use this**

```
body {
background: url('../images/oops.jpg');  

background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-size: 100% 100% ;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.